# how to change the prompt string of the tableviewcell delete-confirmation button

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I just want to change the confirmation button's title of the `TableViewCell` when I want to delete one cell, but I don't find any related property  in the reference. 
I just want to change the title from **delete** to **trash**, anyone know how?

Answer (score 3):

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return @"trash";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Overriding existing methods of UITableViewDelegate.

**Objective - C**

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return @"Trash";
}
```

**Swift**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> String
{ 
      return "Trash"; 
}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Thanks, now I know I should find the doc in the UITableViewDelegate, not the table view.

Comment: Ya it's just forgot to type